# Call paramater value in java query with list return type?

Tags: java, hibernate

So, i have this public list class with the parameter businessGroupId

```
public List<Object[]> getGrades(Long businessGroupId) throws Exception {
        List<Object[]> results = null;
        
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(" select INTERNALID, GRADE_NAME from WOT_GRADE ORDER BY GRADE_SEQ");
        sb.append(" where businessGroupId = :businessGroupId ");
        
        results = (List<Object[]>) getSession().createSQLQuery(sb.toString()).list();

        return results;
    }
```

in my where condition, how to catch the value of the Long businessGroupId paramater in this list return type, the only i know maybe use

```
results.setLong("businessGroupId", businessGroupId);
```

but, this is not working, guys please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like below

```
String sql = "select INTERNALID, GRADE_NAME from WOT_GRADE ORDER BY GRADE_SEQ where businessGroupId = :businessGroupId";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Employee.class); // your entity class
query.setParameter("businessGroupId", businessGroupId);
List results = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

solved! with this :

```
sb.append(" select INTERNALID, GRADE_NAME from WOT_GRADE ");
        sb.append("     where BUSINESS_GROUP_ID = '" + businessGroupId + "' ");
        sb.append("     AND RECORD_FLAG <> 'D' ");
        sb.append(" ORDER BY GRADE_NAME");
```